# Java Swing - Get X,Y From CLick

Tags: java, swing, action

```
public class cPan extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


    }
}
```

I have the above code which catches actions from within my JPanel.

Im confused about how i would get an x,y cordinate from within my JPanel e.g. where i click

So if i click on 100,200 (x,y) i would like to be able to see this.

I've look the function givens from arg0 but cant find anything useful.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: what you need is not `ActionListener`, but  `MouseListener`

Comment: Ahh make sense now lookng at example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) instead. This way, you'll get a [`MouseEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html), from which you can get the clicked point by calling [`MouseEvent#getPoint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getPoint%28%29).

```
public class cPan extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Point p = e.getPoint();
    // or
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class cPan extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
```

should be

```
public class cPan extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
```

more in Oracle turorial [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and with compare with wrong listener [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for [MouseEvents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/MouseEventDemoProject/src/events/MouseEventDemo.java)

Answer (score 2):

`ActionListener` is used to notify you when, well, some kind of nondescript action has occurred.

There is no way to extract information about what caused the action (like mouse click or key action)

To get information about mouse events, you need to use a `MouseListener` attached to the component(s) you are interested in monitoring.

Check out [How to use Mouse Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more information

Answer (score 2):

You need to add mouse listener:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
panel.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (640, 480));
panel.addMouseListener (new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            e.getComponent (), "X: " + e.getX () + ", Y: " + e.getY ());
    }
});

JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Click");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane ().setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
frame.getContentPane ().add (panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack ();
frame.setVisible (true);
```